# How to check Matplotlib's speed in Xcode and increase performance?

Tags: xcode, performance, matplotlib

I'm running into some considerable speed bottlenecks with a Python-Matplotlib-Xcode combination. I know some immediate responses will probably ask "Why are you doing python stuff in Xcode, just man up and use vim" --> I like the organizing ability and the built in version control, it makes elements of my work easier to deal with.

Getting python to run in xcode in the first place was a bit more tricky than I had hoped, but its possible. Now I have the following scenario:

A master file, 'main.py' does all the import stuff for me and sets up some universal formatting to make all the figures (for eventual inclusion in my PhD  thesis) nice and uniform. Afterwards it runs a series of execfile commands to generate whichever graphics I need. Two things I can think of right off the bat:

1) at the very beginning of main.py after I import all the normal python stuff you tend to need, I call a system script which checks whether a certain filesystem is mounted. I keep all my climate model data on there since my local hard drive is too small to deal with all of it at once. Python pauses itself and waits for the system to do its thing, but once the filesystem has been found, it keeps going. Usually this only needs to happen once in the morning when I get to work, or if the VPN server kicked me off for whatever reason. (Side question, it'd be cool to know if theres a trick to automate an VPN login to reconnect as soon as it notices its not connected)

2) I'm not sure how much xcode is using on its own. running the same program from terminal is (somewhat) faster. I've tried to be memory conscience and turn off stuff I don't need while running the python/xcode combination.

Also, python launches a little window whenever I call plt.show(), this in itself takes time, I've considered just saving them as quick png files and opening them with some other viewer, although I guess that would also have to somehow take time to open up. Given how often these graphics change as I add model runs or think of nicer ways of displaying the data, it'd be nice to not waste something on the order of 15 to 30 minutes (possibly more) out of the entire day twiddling my thumbs and waiting for a window to pop up.

Comment: also profilers! http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html.  What do you have in your plots?  There are more efficient ways to do some things (ie `LineCollection` vs 10k `Line2D` objects)

Comment: We can't really help you with out more details.

Comment: The plots differ, but I generally have 2 types: In one case, I plot regular time evolution of a variable, for instance temperature. This is the only thing I've done with Xcode so far. I do those with plt.plot(x,y,options) The other variation, plotting a variable spatially, can be done via the Basemap extension, although I already know this will be even slower...

Answer (score 2):

Benchmark it!

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
# your plotting code
td = datetime.datetime.now() - start
print td.total_seconds() # requires python version >= 2.7
```

Run it in xcode and from the command line, see what the difference is.